# Django PSYCOPG2 db connection

Tags: python, django, multithreading, apache, psycopg2

I have created a django api with the following views.py

```
import datetime
import os
import traceback
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from logging import Formatter
from django.http import HttpResponse
import logging
# from . import models as m
import pandas as pd
import json
import psycopg2 as pg

# logger setup





def resp(status):
    //returns status code


def index(request):
    logger.info('request:' + str(request.GET))
    obj = DAA()
    if request.method == "GET":
        // get values from url request


        if (condition):
            try:
                connection = pg.connect(dbname="dbname", user="user", password="password")
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                response = obj.level1(arguments)
                response = obj.level2(arguments)
                try:
                    // check response
                except Exception as e:
                    # add exception to log


            except Exception as e:
                # add exception to log




        if response :
            json_data = {
                "responseCode": 200,
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "results":
                    [
                        // response
                    ]
            }
            json_dump = json.dumps(json_data)

            return HttpResponse(json_dump, content_type='application/json')
        elif not response :
            json_dump = resp(400)
            return HttpResponse(json_dump, content_type='application/json')


class DAA:
    def level1(arguments):
        GB = []
        if condition:
            query = //query
            try:
                query_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
                response = [i for i in query_df[//xyz]] // get values
            except Exception as e:
                cursor.execute('rollback;')
                # add exception to log
                return None

            gb_data = //response
            GB.append(gb_data)
            return GB
        else :
            argument = argument .upper()
            argument = argument .split(',')
            for i, val in enumerate(argument):
                query = //query
                try:
                    query_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
                    response = [i for i in query_df['xyz']]
                except Exception as e:
                    # add exception to log
                    return None

                gb_data = //response
                GB.append(gb_data)

            return GB

    def level2(arguments):
        if condition:
            argument = []
            try:
                cursor.execute( // query )

                return response

            except Exception as e:
                cursor.execute('rollback;')
                # add exception to log
                return None

        else :
            argument = []
            argument = argument.upper()
            argument = argument.split(',')
            for i, val in enumerate(argument):
                try:
                    cursor.execute( //query )

                except Exception as e:
                    # add exception to log
                    return None

            return response
```

with the above code I am facing the following issues:

1. While testing the application for more than 100 users on jmeter I am getting an error "too many clients already", seems like it is an issue with the postgres database as in the conf file [max_connections = 100] but increasing the connections didn't seems to work for me so please suggest something other than that.
2. While even running the application for less than 100 users I am getting this error "RuntimeError: can't start new thread", so please suggest how to resolve this one ?
3. Note:- please ignore the programming errors as i have only shared the dummy structure of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you closing your connections after you use them, or opening a new one each time?

Could try using a connection pool. Create a file called mydb.py

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.pool
from contextlib import contextmanager

dbpool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(host=<<YourHost>>,
                                          port=<<YourPort>>,
                                          dbname=<<YourDB>>,
                                          user=<<YourUser>>,
                                          password=<<yourpassword>>,
                                          )

@contextmanager
def db_cursor():
    conn = dbpool.getconn()
    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            yield cur
            conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        dbpool.putconn(conn)
```

Then your code could use:

```
import mydb

def myfunction():
    with mydb.db_cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""Select * from blahblahblah...""")
```

Comment: What about the dataframe queries "query_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)"

Comment: Should I now use "query_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, dbpool)" instead ?